# crystal report grand total doesn't show in report footer

Tags: crystal-reports, footer

I'm working on a report. The sections look like the following:

- Report Header
- Page Header

  - PH1
  - PH2
- Group Header1
- Group Header2
- Details
- Group Footer2
- Group Footer1
- Page Footer
- Report Footer

I have a couple of questions here:

1. On the first page, there are two complete group1(group-a, group-b), and part of the data from next group (group c). The vertical lines stop at the end of group-b. Group-a and group-b have grid but group-c has no grid at all. But all vertical lines look fine on the following pages. 
   [image: no grid for extra work order]
2. I created a few summary objects under report footer, but nothing shows up, not even the text object I put there for testing. I've played around with the section export, but so far, no luck.

Please help me with the questions, thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for line issue, one solution is to create separate line segments for each section. They need to be carefully positioned to line up vertically and sized to span the exact height. Use the editor dialog because mouse positioning just won't work right.

In old versions of Crystal there must have been a lot bugs because I could crash the app dozens of time before getting it right. Eventually I figured out how to avoid the crashes pretty well but I can't remember the details now. It's a big hassle all the way around.

Diagnosing the other issue is probably easier with a view of the designer.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Crystal? Is there a page break before the report footer?

I know you already tried the text object, but try adding a background color to the report footer to confirm that it's present in the output.

Comment: Runtime is 13.0.0.99 and the CR for VS 2010 is 13.0.0.99 as well.         There isn't a page break before the report footer. And I added some background color to the report, it still doesn't show up

Comment: What kind of conditional formatting is on that section? Suppress?

Comment: And I hate to confirm the obvious, but you are certain that you're checking the final page of the output?

Comment: :), ya, it's not suppress, and I checked the last page.

Comment: it's also very strange that if a group of data are separated on different pages, the part shows up in the first page has no vertical line. Do you know what kind of settings may cause this?

Comment: I used to work with Crystal a whole lot back about ten years ago. I think one of the tricks with lines used a group footer that displayed on the bottom of every page. But that line stuff was always really screwy and it used to crash the application a lot also. I thought maybe they had fixed a lot of those bugs by now.

Comment: Thank you, here is all the settings I have for each sections. Report Header -> keep together;
Page Header ->  ;
PH1 ->  ;
PH2 -> ;
Group Header1-> keep together ; 
Group Header2-> keep together ; 
Details-> keep together, suppress blank section ; 
Group Footer2-> keep together ; 
Group Footer1-> keep together ; 
Page Footer->suppress blank section ; 
Report Footer-> keep together ;

Comment: I think a screenshot would be the most helpful.